# Enable Kubernetes Garbage collection even disk space available

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Kubernetes garbage collection that removes unused images, runs only when disk space is low

How to run garbage collection even when disk space is available and not full.

Answer (score 1):

`... runs only when disk space is low`

> The kubelet performs garbage collection on unused images every **five minutes and on unused containers every minute**...

You can push further by changing the kubelet [settings](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/garbage-collection/#containers-images). Example, if you changed `HighThresholdPercent: 60`; the clean-up starts when the disk usage crossed 60% and the process will bring it down to `LowThresholdPercent: 50`.

Comment: By default the below kubelet configurations for image are ----    "HighThresholdPercent": 85,
"LowThresholdPercent": 80,

 If we change these configurations to 50 or 60 or 0, will it remove unused images when disk space reaches 50 or 60???. if we set 0 will it delete the unused images every time GC runs??. Also what is the impact of system if these values are set to 0, any instability issue on device??

Comment: See the updated answer. Low threshold of zero means no unuse image will ever exist on the host, every call to use such image will result to pull; if this is acceptable by you.

Comment: Thanks, understood if set to 0, no unused image will be there. One more thing want to confirm, If we set to 0, will it have any impact on kubernetes node/kubelet performance or any in-stability issues?

Comment: "Performance" is subjective. Example if you run lots of small jobs and the node keep pulling images. Would it cause instability? network performance degrade? How about image that has size > 1GB? You will have to test your cluster as no workloads are the same. If your cluster runs only specific workload; does not change once created; is of course a different story.